# HTML page not scrolling in windows phone 8

Tags: jquery, html, cordova, windows-phone-8, phonegap-build

I am creating a hybrid app for android , IOS and windows phone and its working fine for android and IOS but for windows phone 8 the scroll is not working and i had  added overflow-y:scroll property for all the HTML pages in windows but again its affecting my jquery swipe , fixed header element and popup feature.
Issues
1-fixed header-bouncing along with the whole page
2-Jquery swipe- not working when the page is scrolling 
3-popup- showing weird opacity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add -ms-touch-action: pan-y to body/element that needs scrolling.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/windows/apps/hh767313.aspx